# MVC Login screen keeps showing up when switching pages

Tags: asp.net-mvc, session, authentication

Currently learning stuff with MVC and at the point of adding a login screen before the users are able to browse the site menu.
I googled around and found a way to add authentication which only by adding this on top of HomeController:

```
[Authorize]
```

I also added this on web.config:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" timeout="2880"/>
</authentication>
```

Now the login works, but as soon as I change page(s), it will ask for login again and it will not be redirected to the page I was last on.

How is it to retain the logged user session in MVC?

EDIT: code for the login

```
//Login
    public ActionResult Login()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Login(UserAccount user)
    {
        using (OurDbContext db = new OurDbContext())
        {
            var usr = db.userAccount.Single(u => u.Username == user.Username && user.Password == user.Password);
            if (usr != null)
            {
                Session["UserID"] = usr.UserID.ToString();
                Session["Username"] = usr.Username.ToString();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Username or Password is wrong.");
            }
        }
        return View();
    }
    public ActionResult LoggedIn()
    {
        if (Session["UserId"] != null)
        {
            return View();
        }
        else
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Login");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Show your code for the Login methods

Comment: @StephenMuecke Ok I added it above

Comment: You don't add the details to `Session`. And you certainly never store passwords in plain text in a database (you hash them). I suggest you go t the MVC site and work through the tutorials, in the sections on [Security, Authentication and Authorization](https://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/security)

Comment: @StephenMuecke noted. Grabbing that from googling also since I still getting the grasp of developing with MVC. But good suggestion will look for the MSDN tutorial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add following line to set authentication ticket for current session inside your if (usr != null){} condition

```
FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(usr.UserID.ToString(), false);
```

Comment: I am getting the "FormsAuthentication does not exist in the current context" error. Should I import something first?

Comment: Add reference "using System.Web.Security".

Comment: thanks :) On unrelated note, do you know the reference for using "userDbEntities"?

Comment: Please mark it as answer if it solved your problem. For userDbEntities, what is the class type for that?

Comment: I tried to add it under ActionResult method. Is that what you mean?

Comment: @OreoFanatics Are you talking about reference? You need to add it on top section of controller class where you will find other references also.